# Draw arrows in 3D, based on package rgl

Tags: r, rgl

I would like to draw 3D arrows in my plot3d plot using the rgl library as mentioned for example [here](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/compositions/man/arrows3d.html).
But apparently arrows3d is not part of the package, is it deprecated or future music as `??arrows3D` returns:

```
No vignettes or demos or help files found with alias or concept or title matching ‘arrows3D’ using fuzzy matching.
```

Comment: `arrows3D` is a function in the **compositions** package. You might also want to  have a look at `arrow3d` in the **heplots** package.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875133/visulize-a-3d-vector-in-r/36875423#36875423

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest `rgl` (version 0.95.1470, available only on R-forge at the moment; see [How do I install the latest version of rgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142762/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-rgl) for how to get it) has a function `arrow3d()` modelled after the `heplots::arrow3d` function, but expanded quite a bit.

It can draw arrows like the `heplots` function (i.e. made up of line segments), or as flat polygons, or as extrusions of polygons, or as rotations of polygons.  The `?arrow3d` help example currently does this:

```
xyz <- matrix(rnorm(300), ncol = 3)
plot3d(xyz)
arrow3d(xyz[1,], xyz[2,], type = "extrusion", col = "red")
arrow3d(xyz[3,], xyz[4,], type = "flat",      col = "blue")
arrow3d(xyz[5,], xyz[6,], type = "rotation",  col = "green")
arrow3d(xyz[7,], xyz[8,], type = "lines",     col = "black")
arrow3d(spriteOrigin = xyz[9:12,],            col = "purple")
```

which produces this output:

[image: arrow3d example]

Normally it draws just one arrow per call, but if you ask for 3D sprites (as in the `purple` example) it can draw multiple copies of the same arrow.

Answer (score 3):

The `matlib` package, https://cran.r-project.org/package=matlib, contains another version: `arrows3d` that takes a matrix of (x,y,z) coordinates and draws an arrow for each.  Another function, `vectors3d` draws a collection of vectors (from an origin) and provides for labeling each.

These are tuned to drawing geometric 3D diagrams and have nicer arrow heads composed of 3D cones.

They are used, for example in the function `regvec3d` that draws a 3D representation of a bivariate multiple regression model, `y ~ x1 + x2` in mean-deviation space.

Here is an example, using `vectors3d`

```
library(rgl)
library(matlib)
vec <- rbind(diag(3), c(1,1,1))
rownames(vec) <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "J")
open3d()
vectors3d(vec, color=c(rep("black",3), "red"), lwd=2, radius=1/25)
# draw the XZ plane, whose equation is Y=0
planes3d(0, 0, 1, 0, col="gray", alpha=0.2)
vectors3d(c(1,1,0), col="green", lwd=2, radius=1/25)
```

[image]